# MySql carregar a última compra de cada item

Tags: mysql

Eu posso uma listagem de fichas técnicas de alguns produtos onde preciso fazer o cálculo do custo levando em consideração apenas as últimas compras feitas de cada item de uma ficha técnica.

Por exemplo, para fazer um bolo vou utilizar os itens conforme a seguinte ficha técnica:

```
tb_ficha
id | produto | custo_total
1  | Bolo    | 10.25

tb_ficha_produto
id | id_ficha | id_produto | quantidade
1  | 1        | 7 (trigo)  | 0.400
2  | 1        | 8 (ovos)   | 2.000
3  | 1        | 9 (sal)    | 0.010
```

A organização das compras segue conforme as tabelas a seguir:

```
tb_compra
id | data_compra | valor_produtos | valor_entrega

tb_compra_produto
id | id_compra | id_produto | quantidade | valor
```

E a tabela que vincula tudo, que é a de cada produto individual:

```
tb_produto
id | nome   | materia_prima...
1  | Trigo  | 1
2  | Álcool | 0
```

A *query* a seguir está me retornando quase que corretamente os resultados. Consigo filtrar e obter a lista de `id` e `valor` somente dos produtos que pertencem a ficha técnica. Porém, se houve 10 compras do produto, irão aparecer 10 resultados na *query*, sendo que eu preciso apenas do último registro. Lembrando que eu devo levar em consideração o campo `data_compra`, pois as compras não são cadastradas em ordem sequencial.

```
SELECT a.id_produto, a.valor_unitario, b.data_compra

FROM tb_compra_produto a

INNER JOIN tb_compra b
    ON b.id = a.id_compra

INNER JOIN tb_ficha_produto c
    ON c.id_produto = a.id_produto

INNER JOIN tb_ficha d
    ON d.id = :id_ficha //recebo de uma variável
    AND d.id = c.id_ficha
```

Como posso ajustar a *query* para retornar apenas o resultado desejado? Ou qual outro método posso utilizar para obter o mesmo resultado?

--

```
Resultados obtidos:
id_produto | valor | data
3          | 14.89 | 2019-10-12
5          | 07.90 | 2019-10-09
5          | 08.90 | 2019-10-01
3          | 13.90 | 2019-10-09
5          | 08.90 | 2019-09-28
3          | 14.80 | 2019-09-27
9          | 09.90 | 2019-10-10
9          | 09.90 | 2019-09-07
5          | 07.99 | 2019-09-23
3          | 14.80 | 2019-09-25
9          | 10.90 | 2019-09-30

Resultados desejados:
id_produto  | valor | data
3           | 14.89 | 2019-10-12
5           | 07.90 | 2019-10-09
9           | 10.90 | 2019-10-10
```

Comment: Creio que você pode tentar fazer isso colocando uma condição em seu ```ORDER BY```, mais ou menos assim: ```ORDER BY b.data_compra DESC LIMIT 1```

Comment: @Leo Já tentei isso, mas ele vai retornar apenas 1 registro e não 1 registro de cada produto.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de resolver isso seria fazer uma query para retornar o último ID de compra de cada produto. Para fazer isso, você poderia fazer assim:

```
select MAX(id) from tb_compra as T1 INNER JOIN tb_compra_produto AS T2 ON T.id = T2.id_compra GROUP BY id_produto
```

Você poderia usar o resultado deste select MAX como critério na sua consulta, a sua query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT a.id_produto, a.valor_unitario, b.data_compra
FROM tb_compra_produto a
INNER JOIN tb_compra b
    ON b.id = a.id_compra
    ORDER BY b.data_compra
INNER JOIN tb_ficha_produto c
    ON c.id_produto = a.id_produto
INNER JOIN tb_ficha d
    ON d.id = :id_ficha //recebo de uma variável
    AND d.id = c.id_ficha
WHERE b.id in (
select MAX(id) from tb_compra as T1 INNER JOIN tb_compra_produto AS T2
ON T.id = T2.id_compra GROUP BY id_produto
)
```

Comment: Ainda não funcionou. Quando faço somente o primeiro exemplo que você passou, ele retorna uma lista de ID's porém se repetem. A segunda query executa porém ainda retorna diversos resultados para o mesmo produto, igual como mencionado na minha questão.

Comment: Fiz alguns ajustes e melhorei um pouco o resultado, mas ainda não consegui obter o resultado correto. O que eu acredito que esteja acontecendo é que quando executo a query com `MAX(id)` ele retorna o id máximo de todos os produtos. Se houver uma compra onde coincida de ter um produto da ficha e um sem vínculo, ainda assim ele vai puxar.

Comment: Outra coisa que notei, pegar o `Max(id)` não resolve. Se eu cadastrar uma compra de outubro e depois uma de agosto, ele vai considerar o `Max(id)` a de agosto, sendo que a mais recente foi a de outubro.

Answer (score -1):

utilize uma sub consulta

```
select * 
from compra
inner join (select max(id)as id,item from compra group by item) as _last on compra.id=_last.id
```